# Select listvalue and autopopulate formfield

Tags: javascript, acrobat, formfield

hope someone can help me with this one.
I need to select a value from a List and then populate another Formfield with a specific value depending on what i select in the list, in this case e.g. number 1995 if i select value "12" (im not sure if this has the right syntax in script below) in the selectionlist the "Formfield_1" should be populated with the value 1995 and if i select value "18" in the selectionlist, the "formfield_1" should be autopoulated with the number 2995  i, how do i resolve this?

example:

```js
var a = this.getField("SelectionsList").value;
var b = this.getField("SelectionsList").value;
var c = this.getField("Formfield_1").value;
if( a = "12") event.value c = "1995";
if( b = "18") event.value c = "2995";
```

As you can se i have difficulties with the syntax in how i get values in var **a** **b**  and populate the desired value in var **c**
i have chosen to run this as a calcutlation from the properties tab "Format" and Custom keystrokescripts in the selectionsList, maybe it shouldnt be placed there at all?, i want it to do the calculations when/after a selection is done in the SelectionsList.

Comment: Are the results from the selection of the list unique (meaning that for example 1995 has exactly one selection?

Comment: It might be a good idea to have a quick look at general JavaScript syntax, and then also at the Acrobat JavaScript documentation which is part of the Acrobat SDK, downloadable from the Adobe website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is

```
var a = this.getField("SelectionList").value;
if( a == "12") event.value = "1995";
```